# get public folders using microsoft graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to get public folders with no luck and I cannot find anything related to it on microsoft graph documentation, is it possible to get public folders added to any mailbox on the same tenant?
Thanks!

Comment: My tentative answer is no. I'm asking around for a firm answer.

Comment: Were you able to confirm the answer @MichaelMainer?

Comment: You can't access public folders via Graph API. I suggest that you pile on this feature request: [PF request 1](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/35370430-public-folder-support-in-graph-api) and [PF request 2](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/35055997-expose-in-place-archive-and-public-folders-to-grap)

Comment: Those links appear to be dead now.
Anyone know if this has moved on?

Answer (score 1):

PublicFoldersRoot does not work in Graph Explorer. ArchiveMsgFolderRoot did not work either.

These worked. And I assume any other mailbox WellKnownFolderName will work.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}/mailFolders/MsgFolderRoot
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}/mailFolders/Root
```

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't great information or documentation on this topic, but it looks like you can access public folders by specifying the `PublicFoldersRoot` [WellKnownFolderName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.wellknownfoldername?view=exchange-ews-api)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}/mailFolders/PublicFoldersRoot
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}/mailFolders/PublicFoldersRoot/childFolders
```

Comment: Result when trying this was 400 bad request:
        "code": "ErrorInvalidOperation",
        "message": "The distinguished folder name is unrecognized."